# Java, code to print sum of two elements in list not working

Tags: java

can someone explain what is wrong with this code? Why it is not printing sum of these two elements?

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(seinRuutS.split(" "));
List<Integer> seinRuutX = list.stream().map(s -> Integer.parseInt(s))
        .collect(Collectors.toList())
Log.d("qwer", seinRuutX[0] + seinRuutX[1]);
```

Comment: I tried fixing your code formatting, but it doesn't compile as written. Please post your real code

Comment: Yes, thank you for editing it. 
Did you just added tab before every line to make it look like real code?
Every time i post a question i get banned for 3 days.

Comment: what is `seinRuutS`? seinRuutX[0]? maybe seinRuutX.get(0)? But to be honest I have no idea what have you tried to achieve.

Comment: Running your code throws an Exception? Or are there any error message or only a blank screen?

Comment: seinRuutS is variable and it comes from this:
EditText seinRuut = findViewById(R.id.ruutPikkus);
                String seinRuutS = seinRuut.getText().toString();

Comment: If i run it: 
error: array required, but List<Integer> found

Comment: Show the full error message (that is extremely key information and should have been in the question from the start). Also, if the error is occurring in the chained code where you create and work on the stream, de-chain that code, so you can see *exactly* where the errors are coming from. You need to up your question asking game, and that may be why you are getting those bans.

Comment: Thats everything i get from it 
error: array required, but List<Integer> found
Im trying to calculate with edit text input. First i take the input and convert it to list of strings (i think it turns into list of strings), then i try to make it a list of ints and that does not work.

Comment: Note: you can take the first two elements of the stream, then sum it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that `seinRuutX` is not an array and therefore you can not use `seinRuutX[0]` or `seinRuutX[1]` to access the elements in it. Since it is a `List`, the elements should be accessed as `seinRuutX.get(0)` and `seinRuutX.get(1)` e.g.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class LoginProgram {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String seinRuutS = "10 20";
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList(seinRuutS.split(" "));
        List<Integer> seinRuutX = list.stream().map(s -> Integer.parseInt(s)).collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(seinRuutX.get(0) + seinRuutX.get(1));
        // Log.d("qwer", (seinRuutX.get(0) + seinRuutX.get(1)));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
30
```

Comment: This answer looks like a duplicate to me

Comment: Can you show how to use it with "Log.d"?
I tried it with Log.d and it returned "int cant be converted to string"
Also, is it good ide to try if code works in android studio using "Log.d"?

Comment: Okey, it is working now. Thank everybody for their time. :)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the subscript operator on Lists so this
`Log.d("qwer", seinRuutX[0] + seinRuutX[1]);`

should be changed to 
`Log.d("qwer", seinRuutX.get(0) + seinRuutX.get(1));`